# Script to temporarily drop admin privileges

Tags: security, bash, macos

### Description

The aim of my [project](https://github.com/miheerdew/delayed-admin) is to allow administrators to drop privileges for reasons of self-control. Currently, it works only on MacOS Sierra but the concept should be extensible to any Unix compatible system.

The sudoers mechanism is the workhorse. By adding a file in `sudoers.d/` the administrator user (let's call him `my-admin`) is given permissions to run the script `admin-helper` as root.

The `admin-helper` script when run, toggles `my-admin`'s membership from the `admin` group. When the `my-admin` is not in the `admin` group, the user is only added after the script sleeps for 20 min.

### Files

#### admin-helper

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e -u
username=$SUDO_USER
delay=$((60*20)) #20 minutes
uGuid=$(dscl . -read /Users/$username/ GeneratedUID | sed -nE 's/GeneratedUID: (.*$)/\1/p')

if groups "$username" | grep -q -w admin; then
    dscl . -delete /Groups/admin GroupMembers "$uGuid"
    echo "Removed '$username' from admin. You may need to logout for changes to take effect."
else
    echo "'$username' is not an admin"
    echo "Sleeping for $delay seconds staring from $(date '+%D %T')"
    sleep "$delay"

    if [[ -z "${1+x}" ]]; then
       echo "Adding '$username' to admin group"
       dscl . -append /Groups/admin GroupMembers "$uGuid"
    else
       echo "Executing command as root"
       $1
    fi
fi
```

#### admin.sudoers

```
  User_Alias DELAYED_ADMINS = my-admin
  Cmnd_Alias ADMIN_HELPERS = /usr/local/bin/admin-helper

  DELAYED_ADMINS ALL=(root) ADMIN_HELPERS
```

### Usage

This is the installation process:

```
  sudo mkdir -p /private/etc/sudoers.d/
  EDITOR="cp admin.sudoers" sudo visudo -f /private/etc/sudoers.d/admin
  sudo cp admin-helper /usr/local/bin/admin-helper
```

The subsequent usage is:

```
sudo admin-helper
```

or

```
sudo admin-helper "whoami"
```

### Review

Some of the points I want a review for include:

- The way to add/remove user from the `admin` group. Perhaps there is a better cross-platform way of doing this.
- Potential security issues. Possibility of locking oneself out from the admin privilages.
- Better/safer way to do implement installation or uninstallation.

**EDIT:**

The way I use this script is to have my privileges dropped most of the time, and only regain them (by running the script 20min before) when I need to do admin stuff.

**Purpose/Example usage**

The whole reason behind having the delay before gaining admin privileges is to prevent  `my-admin` from gaining them at whim. As a concrete example, suppose `my-admin` wishes to use MacOS parental control settings on himself.  He can do so by dropping admin privileges using `admin-helper`,  then setting parental controls for `my-admin` using another administrator account (and then forgo access to the other admin account). Now suppose `my-admin` wants to disable the parental-controls, he must regain privileges by running `admin-helper` script again, and only then he can disable parental-controls. For this he has to wait for 20min which is a good thing. Say parental-controls prevented him from viewing Facebook. This means that he can no longer open that Facebook tab on whim while he is still doing important work. He can always decide that, "I will run Facebook after 20min", but that decision too can be changed anytime within 20 minutes by interrupting the `admin-helper` script while it is sleeping.

An analogy would be that you have a box of candies that only opens 20min after you tell it to. Will you eat the same amount of candies that you would eat if you could open the box instantly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @janos's usability suggestions, the following seems to be a better way:

### Installation:

Create a new group called `delayed-admin` and copy these files to their respective locations.

#### /usr/local/bin/delayed

This script reads the delay from `/etc/delay.conf`, sleeps for those many seconds, and then executes the command passed in the argument (or executes the shell if there are no arguments)

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e -u

CONFIG_FILE='/etc/delay.conf'

# use integer variable to ensure that delay is always an integer regardless of the contents of the CONFIG_FILE.
declare -i delay=$(cat "$CONFIG_FILE")

CMD=${@:-/bin/bash}

echo "Sleeping for $delay seconds staring from $(date '+%D %T')"
sleep $delay
echo "Running command '$CMD'"

$CMD
```

#### /etc/sudoers.d/delayed-admin

Allow everyone in the `delayed-admin` group to run `/usr/local/bin/delayed` as root.

```
%delayed-admin ALL = /usr/local/bin/delayed
```

#### /etc/delay.conf

The number of seconds that the `delayed` script will sleep for, before executing any command.

```
1200
```

### Usage:

If `my-admin` wants to have delayed administrator access, he should be moved form the `admin` group to the `delayed-admin` group and can then run the commands:

```
sudo delayed cmd #run "cmd" as root after a delay of 1200 sec
```

or

```
sudo delayed #root shell after a delay of 1200 sec
```

Comment: @janos: check this out

Comment: `/etc/delay.conf` is not a great idea. It's not great to pollute `/etc` with custom stuff, and the name is too generic. A better way would be putting this configuration in the same dir as the script itself. Or, if you don't mind letting users change the default delay, you could put it in the user's home directory, or use an environment variable.

Comment: @janos, the delay should only be configurable by root. I can change the name to `delayed-admin.conf`, but is there another way to maintain configuration which can be modified by root only?

Answer (score 3):

#### Usability

The current script works in a dual mode:

- When run without parameters, it toggles group membership
- When run with a parameter, the parameter is executed as root, on the condition that the user is *not* currently an admin

I find the conditional execution in the second mode a bit confusing.
That is, when a parameter is given, but the user is admin,
the command won't be executed.
Instead the script will drop membership.
If you really want to execute the command you have to re-run the same command line, which could be annoying.

I suggest to change the behavior so that when a parameter is given,
execute it always, after the delay, regardless of the membership status.
I think this won't conflict with your main purpose,
but it would improve the usability of the script.

#### Cross-platform way to add/remove users

As a first step to making the script more portable,
it would be good to separate the platform dependent parts from the platform independents ones, for example:

```
add_to_admin() {
    dscl . -append /Groups/admin GroupMembers "$uGuid"
}

remove_from_admin() {
    dscl . -delete /Groups/admin GroupMembers "$uGuid"
}
```

You could have the platform-specific implementations in separate files,
and then source the appropriate flavors as needed.

#### Minor technical improvements

Instead of `sed -nE 's/GeneratedUID: (.*$)/\1/p'` to get the UID part,
it would be simpler to use `cut -f2 -d' '` or `awk '{ print $2 }'`.

This seems to check if `$1` empty:

> ```
> if [[ -z "${1+x}" ]]; then
> ```

Unless I'm missing something, this is equivalent but simpler:

```
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
```

When `$1` appears in the middle or near the end of a script,
it can be hard to remember where it comes from and what it's supposed to be.
It's better to assign command line arguments to a meaningful variable early in the script, and refer to them by that name.
That also makes it easier to find all locations where it is used.
For example, you could put near the top of the file:

```
cmd=$1
```

Comment: Also, I have added the intended purpose and a usage example to the question. That was perhaps not very clear before.

Comment: I think I can still do what you say. I can create a new group (called `delayed-admin`) and add an entry in sudoers file to allow the group to run sudo command with a delay. `my-admin` then has to just add himself to the `delayed-admin` group, and remove himself from the `admin` group once.

Comment: @Miheer I think that would make both the concept and the implementation simpler, so it seems a good idea.

Comment: @Miheer I added a new Usability section at the top.